# terminate instance; Amazon cloudwatch

Tags: c#, asp.net, amazon-web-services, cloudwatch

Im guessing PutMetricAlarm is the solution.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricAlarm.html

I tried this:

```
Dimension instance = new Dimension();
instance.Name = "InstanceId";
instance.Value = "<i-02e1d855>";
PutMetricAlarmRequest sample =new PutMetricAlarmRequest();
sample.Dimensions.Add(instance);
sample.AlarmName = "SSample";
sample.ComparisonOperator = "LessThanThreshold";
sample.Threshold = .10;
sample.Statistic = "Average";
sample.Period = 300;
sample.EvaluationPeriods = 3;
sample.MetricName = "Metric Name";
sample.Namespace = "name space";
sample.Unit="Percent";
PutMetricAlarmResponse sampleres = cloudwatch.PutMetricAlarm(sample);
```

but nothing happens.
did I do something wrong?
and how can I add AlarmActions? that will terminate my instance when alarm triggers.

Please help.
thanks

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add these two lines

```
PutMetricAlarmRequest alarmreq=new PutMetricAlarmRequest()
    .withActionsEnabled(true)
    .withAlarmActions("arn:aws:automate:us-east-1:ec2:stop");
```

//This stops the instance in the requests